# How can I match just the text at left, using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to match this regex pattern here. What I             want to do is match the skill name, and not the descriptions to the right.

```
Earthstone        Creating a physical link to the powers of the earth.
Recall Earthstone Recalling the Earthstone to your hands.
Earthsense        Seeing through darkness.
Walkwater         Walking on water as if it were stone.
Hand of Eden      Channeling powers of the earth.
Dustblast         Blasting dust at someone.
Earthquake        Creating an earthquake underneath someone.
Stonewall         Creating a large wall of stone.
Earth Strength    Protective earth magics.
Sandstorm         Whipping up a great storm of sand.
Pelting           Using the earth to stun your opponent.
Quicksand         Causing the earth to take hold of someone.
Stone             Encasing someone in stone.
Flesh             Releasing someone from stone.
Rockstrike        Pelting an enemy with rocks.
Tremor            Causing target to lose balance or focus.
Stoneskin         Turning your skin to stone.
Gravity           Increasing the gravitational pull in an area.
Golem             Summoning a stone golem to fight for you.
Pillar of Salt    A huge pillar of salt to lift you out of danger.
Landslide         Causing a devastating landslide.
Soul of Earth     Drawing strength from mountains.
```

To explain further, each left-sided text is a skill, the sentences on the right are the descriptions. How can I match only the skills?

Comment: Regular expressions cannot match irregular text. If you're using `\t` (tab) separators, you could grab all the text before the tab.

Comment: What is the character between the skill and its description? Unless it's something other than a space, looks like you're out of luck.

Comment: It is all spaces, no tabs.

Comment: You can get almost there if you can live without "Recall Earthstone", or any other skill with only a single trailing space. Is that an option?

Comment: Hrm... Well no I need to match all of them. If it can't match "Recall Earthstone" completely then is there a way to match just the first word instead (if it gets part of the description)?

Comment: @JonathanMicaelPicazo you can replace those spaces with tabs and match the `\t` tab, but you can't match an arbitrary number of spaces when there are others in the left and right side. The other option is you have at least two spaces between the left and right and you could match more than one space: `\s{2,}`

Comment: Is that FOR SURE all of the ones you need to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match ALL up until the 18th character, use:

```
^[\w\s]{18}
```

You can then strip trailing whitespace.

Here's a working example: http://regex101.com/r/zB1lY7

An easier way to do this would be to `split` on the 18th character, and then retrieve the first split (`group 0`) and trim whitespace on that. You didn't provide a language in your question, so I can't write you an example.

Comment: I use Lua, so the `trim()` function will work perfectly with this. Thank you!

Comment: Why use a regexp for a substring of known bounds?

Comment: @maček exactly, hence "An easier way to do this would be to split on the 18th character..."

Answer (score 1):

The longest skill, "Recall Earthstone", is 17 characters long, so the following regex will match the skill and leave out trailing spaces:

```
^.{1,16}\w
```

Here's a demo: http://regex101.com/r/aV1qG1

Answer (score 1):

You can replace those spaces with tabs and match the `\t` tab delimiter, but you can't match an arbitrary number of spaces when there are others in the left and right side. The other option is you have at least two spaces between the left and right and you could match more than one space: `\s{2,}`

In your case what I'd suggest is to match the first 18 characters, which seems to be consistent, then **don't** capture anything after that:

```
/(.{18}).*/
```

You can then trim the whitespace in whatever implementation language you are using.

**Here's a demo:** http://regex101.com/r/eV3eJ7

It would be easier **not** to use regex for this however. Not sure what language you are using to implement this since it's not tagged, but here's a PHP example:

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    // output the first 18 characters
    // with whitespace trimmed off
    echo trim(substr($line, 0, 18)) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Here's a demo**: https://eval.in/81986

Answer (score 1):

If your implementation has positive lookbehind, you can take advantage of the fact that your input is lined up in columns.  This regex should leave the name in the first capture group and the description in the second:

```
^(.{1,17}?)\s+(?<=^.{18})(.*)$
```

The second group will only match after 18 characters from the start of the line, while the first group will match only as much as it needs to get to the unbroken whitespace before the second group.

I see you're using Lua, so you need to be using PCRE for this to work in your case.  I tried it with lrexlib-pcre and it worked fine:

```
local rex = require 'rex_pcre'
local spells = io.open('spells.txt','r')
local rx = rex.new'^(.{1,17}?)\\s+(?<=^.{18})(.*)$'
for line in spells:lines() do
   name, description = rx:match(line)
   print("spell is \"" .. name .. "\"; description is \"" .. description .. "\"")
end
```

The above produces this output:

```
spell is "Earthstone"; description is "Creating a physical link to the powers of the earth."
spell is "Recall Earthstone"; description is "Recalling the Earthstone to your hands."
spell is "Earthsense"; description is "Seeing through darkness."
spell is "Walkwater"; description is "Walking on water as if it were stone."
spell is "Hand of Eden"; description is "Channeling powers of the earth."
spell is "Dustblast"; description is "Blasting dust at someone."
spell is "Earthquake"; description is "Creating an earthquake underneath someone."
spell is "Stonewall"; description is "Creating a large wall of stone."
spell is "Earth Strength"; description is "Protective earth magics."
spell is "Sandstorm"; description is "Whipping up a great storm of sand."
spell is "Pelting"; description is "Using the earth to stun your opponent."
spell is "Quicksand"; description is "Causing the earth to take hold of someone."
spell is "Stone"; description is "Encasing someone in stone."
spell is "Flesh"; description is "Releasing someone from stone."
spell is "Rockstrike"; description is "Pelting an enemy with rocks."
spell is "Tremor"; description is "Causing target to lose balance or focus."
spell is "Stoneskin"; description is "Turning your skin to stone."
spell is "Gravity"; description is "Increasing the gravitational pull in an area."
spell is "Golem"; description is "Summoning a stone golem to fight for you."
spell is "Pillar of Salt"; description is "A huge pillar of salt to lift you out of danger."
spell is "Landslide"; description is "Causing a devastating landslide."
spell is "Soul of Earth"; description is "Drawing strength from mountains."
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to trim trailing white spaces, you can use this in multiline mode (if your regex flavour supports lookbehinds):

```
^.{1,17}(?<!\s)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use regexp if you know the length of the longest spell

```
local f = io.open("spells.txt", "r")

for line in f:lines() do
  name = string.sub(line, 0, 17):gsub("%s+$", "")
  desc = string.sub(line, 19)
  print(string.format("[%s] %s", name, desc))
end
```

Output

```
[Earthstone] Creating a physical link to the powers of the earth.
[Recall Earthstone] Recalling the Earthstone to your hands.
[Earthsense] Seeing through darkness.
[Walkwater] Walking on water as if it were stone.
[Hand of Eden] Channeling powers of the earth.
[Dustblast] Blasting dust at someone.
[Earthquake] Creating an earthquake underneath someone.
[Stonewall] Creating a large wall of stone.
[Earth Strength] Protective earth magics.
[Sandstorm] Whipping up a great storm of sand.
[Pelting] Using the earth to stun your opponent.
[Quicksand] Causing the earth to take hold of someone.
[Stone] Encasing someone in stone.
[Flesh] Releasing someone from stone.
[Rockstrike] Pelting an enemy with rocks.
[Tremor] Causing target to lose balance or focus.
[Stoneskin] Turning your skin to stone.
[Gravity] Increasing the gravitational pull in an area.
[Golem] Summoning a stone golem to fight for you.
[Pillar of Salt] A huge pillar of salt to lift you out of danger.
[Landslide] Causing a devastating landslide.
[Soul of Earth] Drawing strength from mountains.
```